# How do i make these parts of my model smoother and less discolored?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]
So i am pulling final strings together to finish my project and i have these 2(used to be more, but i eliminated them whit knife tool or edge loop) unsmooth or discolored meshes. How do i get rid of them? I tried knife tool and edge loops and they dont seem to really work(that well)....

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid triangle faces, especially where you need smooth curved surfaces. Use quads instead.  [image: tris quads]

I fixed your model's normals to make it renderable but it won't be perfect...
[image: render view]
You can solve some shading issues changing the blue edges back to normal. The blue edges are marked as sharp, this means they won't be smoothed. Some of them have been marked by mistake so you'll have to check.
This is how to "unmark" them :

In edit mode
1- change your selection mode to edge
2- select your edges and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open Edge menu
3- click on clear sharp
[image: clear sharp]

[image]

Comment: Thx, its not useful for me right now(since i have to extensivley modify it(especially fender panels to make it look like a real car when the fender panels get separated from the chassis) and i need every body part of the car(including lights and windows) to be separate meshes, but ill use this fixed stock(in sense of how it came from website, whitout any of the underbody fixes i did to it) model as my V2 to work on when my school project is done/passed, and ill use this import version instead to work on my public version of the Beamng mod!

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your blend file and you have many more shading issues than just the two you pointed out. When modelling, try to keep your geometry clean and use quads where possible. Otherwise you'll run into all sorts of issues when subdividing your mesh later on.

But the main reason for the issues you pointed out is because **ALL your normals** are facing inwards. In edit mode, select all and press Ctrl + N to fix them.
Also, the vertices in the quad from the first picture are not on the same plane.

Fixing your normals and using quads will get you the furthest at this point. I suggest you start there.

Comment: Well i am on a deadline(this is a project i have to do to finish my IT profession school, and the deadline is in a month, and this model is only a tiny component of it(also importing it and physics).

Comment: what happens when i dont flip the normals? Since i cant put much time into the model anymore...Does the model still work after i export it?

Comment: It will cause shading problems, somehow inverting the shadows/highlights and make it look weird.

Comment: but as @michaelh said, it's easy to fix : in edit mode, select all with A key, they use Ctrl+N, that's it. Do this for all objects.

Comment: Thanks, @Bithur to chime in. Yes, Getting your normals right is most important. Don't get confused if your model changes color in the viewport. That's alright. If you look at the render, it will look correct. You can leave the triangles if it looks ok and you don't need to do much else with it.

Comment: Well, i'm afraid it won't be enough... I checked the model and it has doubled topology (tires), custom normals and is mostly made of tris-NGons. A complete retopo is needed to get correct shading.

Comment: True, but it doesn't seem to be much of an option for @Justaparps . Especially if (s)he is not solid on normals and topology, a complete retopo seems a bit unfeasible at this point. I'd suggest to just fix the normals, do a quick preview render and fiddle with the any weird looking parts until they look right. Not pretty or ideal at all. I am aware of that. But sometimes necessary.

Comment: tried some fixing, but it's a long term work, so many things are messed up... fixing there makes things worse here, not talking about UVs..

Comment: @Justaparps the original model could be of some use, can you link it ?

Comment: http://animium.com/2013/05/zaz-968-3d-model

Comment: And i asked them permission(got it on their FB page) if i can use this(probably stolen(one texture of it is from a game, SLRR, the texture is the car chassis one named nonus something) and they gave me permission to use it if i share it for free or make it open source(i went whit first one)

Answer (score 0):

The distortion is because the smooth shading only smooths between the edges; and in the upper image it is simply the transition between two objects that are miss matched.

It is ok to have faces that isn't made of four vertices if you have a reason to but that is a source for errors like this. This should fix it:

[image]

I don't think you should try and have squares and triangles only because that would make the mesh more complicated than necessary.

And the biggest problem is most likely that you have a normal problem. The face is supposed to be on the other side and that make it this weird looking:

[image]

I did open the file, the mesh is to complicated to work with effective and you should try and remove edges and vertices you don't need.

If you want to be lazy you could probably fix it with a *Bevel* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifiers. I don't recommend this method though.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos thanks for the edit that I you made during mine

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you start using a spellchecker

Comment: Thats usaly more confusing when it works with swedish,GB and US at the same time

Comment: It is a lot more confusing for everyone else if you don't. I use both PT and EN at the same time and it is fine

Comment: I don't use spellchecking, but I do use word/phrase prediction on my phone, for Swedish, US and GB at the same time. I have only one problem with it; it invariably changes i to I, otherwise it works flawlessly. Granted spellchecking and word prediction aren't the same, but they are closely related.

Comment: The problem with SW, GB/US word book is that the swedish one have a GB/US extention. The GB and US is confusing to begin with. You should try it before you say that it works.

Comment: @Duane Dibbley, Har du provat att lägga till den tekniska svengelskan till det dessutom? Jag har gjort det för en rapport en gång och efter det går det inte att blanda med engelska.

Comment: Using bevel and/or subsurf on tris will probably make a smoothed shading problem, not a solution.

Comment: No I haven't tried that. That's not something I have a need for in my phone's word prediction. All technical systems have limitations, and I'm not trying to belittle your confusion, but @DuarteFarrajotaRamos does have a point.